# How to check user`s username and password using jdbcAuthentication in spring security

Tags: spring, spring-security

I am trying to log in with my custom Login page using ***jdbcAuthentication***. But when I write username and password spring is returning Forbidden message. I think it is not checking password in database. My question is how to check username and password using ***jdbcAuthentication***

I tried to open new page when user is authorized.

SecurityConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Bean
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.datasource")
    public DataSource ds(){
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
            http.authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                    .antMatchers("/user_list").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/login").usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                    .loginProcessingUrl("/doLogin")
                    .successForwardUrl("/user_list");
    }

    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
                .authoritiesByUsernameQuery("select username, role from myusers where username = ?")
                .usersByUsernameQuery("select username, password, 1 as enabled from myusers where username = ?");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

}
```

MainController

```
@Controller
public class MainController {


    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "login";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user_list",method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String showUsers(){
        return "user_list";
    }

    @RequestMapping("addUser")
    public String addUser(){

        return "user_list";
    }

}
```

login.jsp

```
<h1><center>Give your login details</center></h1>
<form method="post" action="doLogin">
    User name:<input type="text" name="username"><br>
    Password:<input type="password" name="password"><br>
    Submit <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

How can I check username and password of a user in database? Thanks in advance

Comment: Spring Security does that. Judging from your code you are either using plain passwords in the DB (don't) or haven't configured a proper password encoded to handle the encryption of passwords. Also does your user really have `ROLE_ADMIN` as an authority or is is `ADMIN`? If it is the latter use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`.

Comment: I gave role as ADMIN

Comment: Then use `hasAuthority` instead of `hasRole`. the `hasRole` will automatically add the `ROLE_` prefix to `ADMIN`. So it will check if your user has the authorization `ROLE_ADMIN` which it doesn't have because it has `ADMIN`.

Comment: anyway it is not working. Maybe I need to add  PasswordEncoder Bean to my Config. Because I added passwords to database directly and in my code password encoder does not exist

Comment: If you need a `PasswordEncoder` or not depends on how you added the passwords. If they are plain text you don't need one. The fact that you get forbidden generally indicates you are using the wrong expression or roles/authorities for checking access.